# Строковые WinAPI функции

Tags: winapi, строки, c++

Допустим, мне надо использовать строку в какой-л. апишной функции, принимающую один из параметров (и более) переменную типа `LPWSTR/LPCWSTR/LPCSTR`. Все это псевдонимы одного типа. Вот как я поступаю в этом случае:

```
   StringCbCat(szTitle,MAX_LOADSTRING,L"123123");
```

[**StringSbCat Function**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647495(v=vs.85).aspx)

Как видите, последний параметр передан "в чистом виде" без использования переменных. Я использую предикат "L". А можно ли как-то обойтись без предиката, сделав какие-либо предварительные преобразования?

**Спасибо!**

Comment: Уточним: 
с литерой "W" (LPWSTR) - всегда wide, без нее (LPSTR) - всегда обычный char, c литерой "T" (LPTSTR) - в зависимости от настроек проекта (объявлен ли UNICODE или нет)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы будете передавать строку без использования макроса `L` или `_T` (который более универсальный и работает для `TCHAR`), то ваша строка будет автоматически трактоваться как ANSI-строка.

---

Соответственно если в настройках проекта стоит Use Wide Character Encoding, то код не скомпилируется. Единственное, что можно сделать в таком случае - воспользоваться какой-либо функцией для перекодирования LPCSTR -> LPCWSTR, однако **это намного сложнее,** нежели просто использовать L или _T.

Comment: Спасибо, @Asen !

Comment: @Asen, как кстати быть, если вместо текста используется переменная? Как в таком случае указать макрос L ?

Comment: @Jourdan Тут вопрос, откуда у вас взялась переменная. Правильно - вообще избегать ANSI-строчек в Unicode приложениях. Но если все-таки так случилось, то используйте MultiByteToWideChar.

Comment: @Jourdan, никакого L с переменной указывать не надо. Переменная *должна* быть нужного типа, и *должна* содержать правильные (мультибайтовые) символы.

Comment: WTF? @Asen, который раньше был @SingleAsen, говорит спасибо @Asen2, который раньше был просто @Asen. Опять клонов себе наплодил?